# Extract numeric data from string in groovy

Tags: string, groovy

I am given a string that can include both text and numeric data:

Examples:

"100 pounds"
"I think 173 lbs"
"73 lbs."

I am looking for a clean way to extract only the numeric data from these strings.

Here is what I'm currently doing to strip the response:

```
def stripResponse(String response) {
    if(response) {
        def toRemove = ["lbs.", "lbs", "pounds.", "pounds", " "]
        def toMod = response
        for(remove in toRemove) {
            toMod = toMod?.replaceAll(remove, "")
        }
        return toMod
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use `findAll` then convert the results into Integers:

```
def extractInts( String input ) {
  input.findAll( /\d+/ )*.toInteger()
}

assert extractInts( "100 pounds is 23"  ) == [ 100, 23 ]
assert extractInts( "I think 173 lbs"   ) == [ 173 ]
assert extractInts( "73 lbs."           ) == [ 73 ]
assert extractInts( "No numbers here"   ) == []
assert extractInts( "23.5 only ints"    ) == [ 23, 5 ]
assert extractInts( "positive only -13" ) == [ 13 ]
```

If you need decimals and negative numbers, you might use a more complex regex:

```
def extractInts( String input ) {
  input.findAll( /-?\d+\.\d*|-?\d*\.\d+|-?\d+/ )*.toDouble()
}

assert extractInts( "100 pounds is 23"   ) == [ 100, 23 ]
assert extractInts( "I think 173 lbs"    ) == [ 173 ]
assert extractInts( "73 lbs."            ) == [ 73 ]
assert extractInts( "No numbers here"    ) == []
assert extractInts( "23.5 handles float" ) == [ 23.5 ]
assert extractInts( "and negatives -13"  ) == [ -13 ]
```

Comment: Solution that I ended up implementing based on advice above, I only want to grab the first number (if there are multiples I invalidate the response). Thanks @tim_yates !

`def extractNumericData(String response) {
        if(response) {
            def numberList = response.findAll( /[0-9]+.[0-9]*|[0-9]*.[0-9]+|[0-9]+/ )

            if(numberList.size() == 1) {
                return numberList.get(0) as BigDecimal
            } else {
                return -1
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: For some reason I get this: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: spread not yet supported in input.findAll(\d+)*.toInteger()` . ---- And it says on [Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43520) its resolved.

Answer (score 9):

Putting this here for people that also need this.

Instead of creating new question, all I needed was one number from a string.

I did this with regex.

```
def extractInt( String input ) {
  return input.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")
}
```

Where input could be `this.may.have.number4.com` and return `4`

I was receiving error from above answer (probably due to my Jenkins version) - For some reason I get this: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: spread not yet supported in input.findAll(\d+)*.toInteger()` ---- And it says on [Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43520) its resolved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Upvoted because, while it doesn't answer the exact question, provides a nice simple sub-case

Comment: replaceAll and replace with space if you want to parse multiple integers. e.g. input.replaceAll("[^0-9][^0-9]*", " ")

Answer (score 4):

After adding the method below ,`numbersFilter`,via metaClass , you can call it as following :

```
assert " i am a positive number 14".numbersFilter() == [ 14 ]
assert " we 12 are 20.3propaged 10.7".numbersFilter() == [ 12,20.3,10.7 ]
assert " we 12 a20.3p 10.7 ,but you can select one".numbersFilter(0) == 12
assert " we 12 a 20.3 pr 10.7 ,select one by index".numbersFilter(1) == 20.3
```

Add this code As BootStrap

```
String.metaClass.numbersFilter={index=-1->
            def tmp=[];
            tmp=delegate.findAll( /-?\d+\.\d*|-?\d*\.\d+|-?\d+/ )*.toDouble()
            if(index<=-1){
                return tmp;
            }else{
                if(tmp.size()>index){
                    return tmp[index];
                }else{
                   return tmp.last();
                }
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since input.findAll( /\d+/ )*.toInteger() doesn't work with Jenkins. You can use this instead.

```
def packageVersion = "The package number is 9.2.5847.1275"
def nextversion=packageVersion.findAll( /\d+/ ).collect{ "$it".toInteger() }
nextversion.add(nextversion.pop()+1)
nextversion = nextversion.join('.')
Result: 9.2.5847.1276
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution, without RegEx. It parses the string into tokens and convert them into a list of numbers or null values. The null values are removed and finally, only first entry is considered (as required).

```
def extractNumericData(String response) {
    response.split(' ')
        .collect { it.isFloat() ? Float.parseFloat(it) : null }
        .findAll { it }
        .first()
}

assert 100 == extractNumericData("100 pounds")
assert 173 == extractNumericData("I think 173 lbs")
assert 73 == extractNumericData("73 lbs.")
```

Answer (score -1):

When parsing line by line a String.contains and String.replaceAll (replace all sequences of non-digit chars with a space) 
then String.split()
 combination is useful, like this:

```
if (line.contains("RESULT:")) {
    l = line.replaceAll("[^0-9][^0-9]*"," ")
    a = l.split()
    pCount1 = Integer.parseInt(a[0])
    pCount2 = Integer.parseInt(a[1])
}
```

The String.findAll solutions are better!
Equivalent:

```
if (line.contains("RESULT:")) {
    a = line.findAll( /\d+/ )*.toInteger()
    pCount1 = a[0]
    pCount2 = a[1]
}
```